# Highlight {{var shipping}} if text is UPS

Tags: magento-1.9, css, invoice, pdf

Using a pdf generator for my invoices and I somehow need to highlight the shipping method if its "UPS"

The code is below for that portion

```
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;"
            valign="top" width="50%">{{var payment}}</td>
        <td style="border-right: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;"
            valign="top">{{var shipping}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but try like this:

```
<tr>
    <td style="border-left: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;" valign="top" width="50%">
        {{var payment}}
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 2px solid #808080;border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;" valign="top">
        {{if var shipping == "UPS"}} <span class="ups-shipping" style="color:#ffb500;">{{var shipping}}</span> {{else}} {{var shipping}} {{/if}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Seemed like it couldve worked but nope :(

Comment: You put exactly the output of var shipping in if var shipping =="here"

Comment: Yes I did. But no change